# Стоит ли использовать Angular.js при создании динамичного приложения (без перезагрузки страницы) на node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

Здравствуйте. Недавно делал небольшой приложение, но оно было на нескольких страницах, сейчас же подумал, что практичнеё будет, если оно будет на одной странице и в нем будут просто синхронно запускаться скрипты и меняться содержание в body через

```
document.body.innerHTML = newBody;
```

Я уже настроил одну страницу из 2, но так-как скоро собираюсь пробоваться на работу с проектом, возможно стоит изучить angular и переписать под него? Что вы посоветуете по этому поводу? стоит ли всё-же оставить замену body, и подлючение к содержимому нужных скриптом, или на angular подобное будет в разы короче и практичнеё?
Проект в виде быстрой авторизации на сайт(без регистрации) и в подальшем выбор партнера для общения в чате. Спасибо

Comment: на первом ангуляре да, можете попробовать. На втором ангуляре такое простенькое приложение браться писать не особо имеет смысл, ибо фрейиворки(в т.ч. ангуляр) предназначены для упрощения разработки средних/большых проектов

Answer (score 0):

Да, проблем нету. Я бы сделал роутер (серверный, а не ангуляровский), который бы отдавал статичную страницу index с подключенными скриптами и ангуляром, а так же другие роутеры, которые принимают REST-запросы, а отвечают информацией в JSON, например POST запросам вида `/newmessage?receiver=user123344&text=hello+world`. А можно чат сделать и на сокетах.

Comment: у меня на сокетах он) точнеё там всё на сокетах)

Comment: Если привязывать авторизацию, можно знатно %$%#@ся с ними, так как сокеты по умолчанию для сервера все одинаковы, они не определяются в объекте запроса req, так как это протокол не http, а свой собственный поверх http. Нужно знать id нужных подключений. Могу подсказать как, если надо, я уже прошел это испытание.

Comment: у меня если четсно пока опыта мало и я пока мало что понимаю) ну смотрите как у меня пока реализованно. У меня одна страница, при публикации я сразу задаю ему рандомный ID с сервера(сервер проверят наличие ID которые уже занесены в дату и возвращает уникальный) потом этот объект летит на сервер и добавляется в json файл - в массив. Потом я уже работаю чисто с ID. Кто-то решил отправить запрос на чат - на сервер литит его ID(который занесен изначально в переменную). Потом с сервера приходит ответ с тем же ID который отослал, идет проверка переменной ID и ID с сервера, если не совпадает - return

Comment: и так со всем функционалом у меня

Comment: Ну это простое решение, не защищённое с точки зрения клиента. Любой клиент имеет доступ к своему id, может отправить сообщение под видом кого-угодно. Кроме того при перезагрузке страницы, открытии другой такой же или при закрытии страницы сессия не сохраняется. По-взрослому можно было б сделать с полноценной авторизацией и с бд (например, монго), вместо json-файла. Ну смотря какая задача. Сам сначала хотел делать, как вы.

Comment: Ну я вот решил делать именно без авторизации, просто быстро зашел, оставил и переписываешься. Конечно в нормальном проекте без авторизации бы не пошло такое) вообще делаю этот проект чтобы с ним пойти пробоваться на работу что скажете?
Ну я ещё не знаю, может это можно было бы IP фиксить(откритие множества окон)

Comment: Я так для учебного проекта просто для себя сделал соц сеть с уведомлениями о дружбе и групповыми чатами на сокетах, с аватарками. Правда запускал только на локалке, все работает ок. Так один и тот же механизм уведомлений работает по всем страницам сайта, а не как на фб или вк, у которых уведомления для каждой страницы пишуться с использованием AJAX long pooling. Стало лень допиливать. Мне кажется, для трудоустройства как синиэ node js дэвелопер нужно очень много опыта. А для просто хорошей работы нужны Angular 1, React/React Native, ES6, сборщики, могут предъявить за тесты chai, mocha.

Comment: я node начал спонтанно брать и очень понравилось) ну вот сейчас думаю ангуляром заняться и с этим проектом и ангуляром вже пробоваться